# Hide app UI after starting Foreground Service

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, maui

I'm developing an Android app with Xamarin (tried Maui and Xamarin.Forms but can't figure out this problem so now trying Xamarin.Android but still struggling). So far I've discovered that my app should invoke a "foreground service", as it needs to constantly monitor the accelerometer. This I can do.
The bit I'm struggling with now is, after invoking the foreground service, how to completely hide the app UI so the foreground service continues to run in the "background"?

Answer (score 0):

1. Customize a Service and override the method `OnStartCommand` , use `StartForeground` method to register Foreground Service, here you need to create a notification to display what you want to monitor.

   ```
   var notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .SetContentTitle(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.app_name))
                .SetContentText(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.notification_text))
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_stat_name)
                .SetContentIntent(BuildIntentToShowMainActivity())
                .SetOngoing(true)
                .AddAction(BuildRestartTimerAction())
                .AddAction(BuildStopServiceAction())
                .Build();

   // Enlist this instance of the service as a foreground service
   StartForeground(Constants.SERVICE_RUNNING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
   ```
2. Use `StartForegroundService` instead of `StartService` with the service intent(On Android 8.0 and higher ).

**Docs** : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services

**Sample** : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/monodroid-samples/applicationfundamentals-servicesamples-foregroundservicedemo/

Comment: Does this hide the app UI once the svc is started?

Comment: No , it just keep working whenever the app is foreground or background .

Comment: Not related to UI at all .

Comment: I would like to be able to completely hide the app UI once the svc is started, so the app no longer appears in the horizontally scrollable list of running apps you get when you tap the ||| icon at the bottom left corner of the screen.

Comment: You can close the app manually , foreground service will still keep on working .